# NonlinearModelFit with a matrix as weights

Tags: fitting, data

I have to fit a non linear model to my data and I am trying to use `NonlinearModelFit`. 
The problem is that I have systematic errors, so the `weights` options is not a simple vector but a matrix.

To be clear: my chi squared is written as:

```
(diff)T*(weight)^(-1)*(diff)
```

Where `diff` is the difference between my model and the data (T means trasposed).

Does anyone have any idea?

I use Mathematica 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the `NonlinearModelFit` yourself? Following the example in the documentation:

Starting with the `data`

```
 data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};
```

Extracting the `ys`, and `xs`

```
 ys = Last /@ data;xs = First /@ data;
```

Defining some ad hoc weights

```
wghts = Table[Exp[-(i - j)^2/8.], {i, Length[ys]}, {j, Length[ys]}]
```

Let us define the corresponding  χ2

```
  χ2 = (ys-Log[a + b xs^2]).wghts.(ys-Log[a + b xs^2]);
```

And carry out the optimization

```
NMinimize[{ χ2, a > 0, b > 0}, {a, b}]
```

(* {0.782788,{a->0.825214,b->1.59388}} *)

to be compared to the `NonlinearModelFit` solution

```
 NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x] // Normal
```

(*  log(1.42633 x^2+1.50632) *)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I don't get your definition of the chi square. I am sorry to ask but: are you sure?

Comment: @mattiav27 yes but if you wish I could write it as: `(ys-Log[a + b xs^2]).wghts.(ys-Log[a + b xs^2])`